# Sql-server stored procedure: update table if a view change

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, timestamp

I made a view from different tables, in this view there are:

```
`name, surname, id, organization, beginDate, endDate`
```

The `endDate` is fetched only when in the source table this value is *null*. If it has a value, means that this person was no more in his organization, so I use this value to know which row I have to load in my view. 
(again, if the value is not null, the row will no more exists in the view)

From this view, I need to create a table with a stored procedure runnable every night with:

```
name, surname, id, organization, beginDate, whenChanged, disabled
```

The first time, this table is the exact copy of the view, with all

```
whenChanged = current_timestamp and all disabled=flase
```

The values should be the same from the view, the whenChanged is a timestamp updated with `current_timestamp` if one or more of the attributes in the view is changed. 
The disabled value (boolean) should be false if the row still exist in the view, and should be true if the row is no more in the view (in the source table it has a non-null `endDate` and it is not fetched from the view)

Any help?

Comment: Make your own answer.. that's all

Comment: Learn more, not answering a wrong mind..idt

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry, I was on mobile and "enter" has a strange behavior... By the way, I'm not totally sure I should use triggers, because I have to do this on many tables, and in some tables, there are no keys.

For example, I have a table assignment with:

Id1, startDate, endDate not null, organization
Id1, startDate2, null, organization
...

Would a trigger work on this table? I need to update another table, with data from assignment, only if id matches and there is another id row with a null endDate. If endDate for each row with that id is not null, then it means that I have to set the disabled value.

Moreover, does triggers Works with views? Is It possible to define a trigger on my table that update that table if my view has changes? I think not...